# Chaning Image Resolution Django

Tags: python, django, image-resizing

I am fetching images from website by using BeautifulSoup, but the resolution is too small, when I want to make image bigger by adding width attribute in src, it loses quality. Is it possible to enlarge image resolution which is downloaded from url? I've tried thumbnail sorl, but then images dissapeared

views.py

```
def home(request):

    source = requests.get('https://lol.gamepedia.com/Ultraliga/Season_3').text
    hours_games = ['17:30', '18:30', '19:30', '20:30', '17:30', '18:30', '19:30', '20:30']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    first_team_images = []
    first_team_images_res = []

    team_image1 = None
    first_team_names = []
    second_team_names = []

    td1s = None
    td2s = None


    tables = soup.find_all('table', class_='wikitable matchlist')

    for table in tables:
        td1s = table.find_all('td', class_='matchlist-team1')
        td2s = table.find_all('td', class_='matchlist-team2')

    for td in td1s:
        span = td.find('span')
        first_team_names.append(span.text)
        span2 = span.find('span', class_='teamimage-left')
        team_image1 = span2.find('img')['src']
        first_team_images.append(team_image1)

    for td in td2s:
        span = td.find('span')
        second_team_names.append(span.text)



    context = {
        'all_teams':zip(first_team_names, second_team_names, hours_games, first_team_images)    
    }



    return render(request, 'profilecontent/home.html', context)
```

template

```
{%extends 'profilecontent/base.html' %}
{%block content%}
    <div class="container-home">
        <div class="home-wrapper home-wrapper-first">
            <p class='home-matches'>Przyszłe mecze <span class='home-week'>W3 D2</span></p>
                <div class="match-wrapper">
                    <ul class='team-schedule-list'>
                        {% for data in all_teams %}

                            <li class='item-team-schedule'><span class='team-describe first-team-name'>{{ data.0 }}</span>
                            <img src="{{data.3}}" width='150' height='150' alt="">
                            <span class='hours-game'>{{ data.2 }}</span>
                            <span class='team-describe2 second-team-name'>{{ data.1 }}</span></li> 

                        {% endfor %}
                    </ul>             
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="home-wrapper home-wrapper-second">

        </div>
    </div>
{%endblock%}
```